# Work around the jQuery-ui Date-Range Bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I been using jquery-ui for my project, lately i found there is a bug in datepicker widget that doesn't take selected date if the date-range is not the current year. take a look at this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wbednarski/45mLv/) . But if you change the year and select some date it takes the correct value. I know there is [BUG](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8873#no1) ticket in jquery they'll solve on next version v.1.11 bcoz jquery ui is big js i am little paranoid to go into the file and modify it. Is there hack or possible solution that i can use now

```
$('#test').datepicker({
    yearRange: '-100:-18',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear:  true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A hackish workaround is to explicitly set the [`defaultDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate) to the one which is shown by the datepicker when it is opened; or to some other reasonable default value:

```
var defaultDate = new Date();
defaultDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
defaultDate.setYear(defaultDate.getYear() - 100);
console.log(defaultDate); // current month, current date, current year - 100
$('#test').datepicker({
    yearRange: '-100:-18',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    defaultDate: defaultDate
});
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/45mLv/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Check this works

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/45mLv/4/)**

```
$('#test').datepicker({
    yearRange: '-100:-18',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear:  true,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
              var d = new Date(dateText);
              var selectedYear = d.setFullYear(parseInt($('.ui-datepicker-year :selected').text())); // selected year      
        $('#test').val([d.getMonth()+1, d.getDate(), d.getFullYear()].join('/'));

           }
});
```